# Fresh install of Windows 7 has slow download/upload speed

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

So hi. I just installed a fresh install of Windows 7 and the internet is running very slow, at around .5 MBPS and on Windows 10 it usually ran at 60-90 MBPS. I configured a lot of settings in CMD, I installed all the drivers I need, and my internet is the same speed.

Here are my stats: Intel I211 Gigabit Network Connection Driver (for wireless, doesn't even work), Intel Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V Driver, and a standard Ethernet wire cable directly plugged into the router.

If I could get help, I would be thankful!

Comment: Windows 7 does not automatically update drivers like Windows 10 does.  Get the Driver Update App from the computer manufacturer’s website and update all drivers

Comment: @John can you provide a link?

Comment: You need to look up the manufacturer’s website, go to the support section for your model, and either download and install all drivers or see if there is an update app - there often is.

Comment: @John I already installed a driver program and scanned earlier, nothing to be updated.

Comment: I am not sure what else to try. Did you download and apply all the Windows 7 service packs and patches?

Comment: @John I am on SP1 and I did install ESU.

Comment: "installed a driver program " 3rd party driver updates are useless, get driver from the manufacturer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A FIX:

I installed the latest wireless drivers, and I went to my wireless connection

I then unplugged the Ethernet cable, problem solved.

Comment: That was my very first suggestion to you and that is what you did.

Comment: @John I updated the Ethernet drivers, still .5 MBPS. That's why I switched to wireless, just to point out.